# Show statistics of CacheBuilder of Guava

Tags: java, guava

Guava's [`CacheBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) offers statistics recording with [`CacheStats`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheStats.html).

I would like to know if there is a way to show how many entries have been invalidated. `evictionCount()` does **not** show those movements because it refers to removed elements by the cleaning process of the `CacheBuilder`.

Comment: You could always track that yourself with a RemovalListener.

Comment: Hi Luis, that is correct, can you write this as an answer please, so I can check it? Thanks a lot

Comment: @johannes.schmidt.delaunay you can always answer your own question - share your implementation, others might appreciate seeing it!